# String Encryption isnt working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, encryption

string encryption is not working in my codeigniter view. i have written below code in my view it shows some error. can any one help me out to fix this issue.

```
<?php
    $this->load->library('encryption');
    $msg = "My Message";
    $encrypt_msg = $this->encryption->encode($msg);
    echo $encrypt_msg;
?>
```

for this i got below error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$encryption

Filename: back-end/edit_wd_view.php

Line Number: 82

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/5ine-portfolio/application/views/back-end/edit_wd_view.php
Line: 82
Function: _error_handler

File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/5ine-portfolio/application/views/back-end/backend_view.php
Line: 1
Function: view

File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/5ine-portfolio/application/controllers/Back_end.php
Line: 552
Function: view

File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/5ine-portfolio/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: encryption library != encrypt class

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->load->library('encryption');
    $key = bin2hex($this->encryption->create_key(16));
    $this->encryption->initialize(
            array(
                    'cipher' => 'aes-256',
                    'mode' => 'ctr',
                    'key' => $key
            )
    );
    $this->encryption->initialize(array('driver' => 'openssl'));
    
    $msg = "My Message";
    $encrypt_msg = $this->encryption->encrypt($msg);
    echo $encrypt_msg;
```

More About https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html